# selenium performance testing using testNG

Tags: node.js, selenium, webdriver

I want to launch 5 browser and login five times in each browser.
I have tried following code. Is this correct way?

```
@Test(threadPoolSize = 5, invocationCount = 5)
public void login(){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using the wrong tools for the job if performance is what you are after
2. If you want to parallely invoke the methods 5 times, apart from what you have mentioned, you would need to set parallel="methods" in your suite.xml or wherever it is you are triggerring from.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite" parallel="methods">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="dj.testing.SuiteTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->

Comment: i'm running with this but still i'm unable to do it

Comment: This may be due to multiple reasons - is your driver launch code thread safe? how are you determining that this is not running in parallel - try printing thread id at the top of your test